# Embeddable overlay chat for websites

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I want to create embeddable HTML/JS code that would add a chat feature to a website.

Preferably, the chat should be "overlaid" over the rest of the website (like facebook/google hangouts chatboxes).

I know of [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript): it provides a chat feature in javascript but I will have to write the UI code by hand.

Even some pointers on how to get it done is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

I found services like: [zopim](https://www.zopim.com/), [zoho chat](https://chat.zoho.com) and others. It seems pretty common. Is there a library (like on github) for such services?

**EDIT:**

I want to implement multiple chat boxes. I cannot find a out of the box solution to this, but I am thinking of combining the backend of [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript) with some javascript (jQuery probably) front-end to communicate with the QuickBlox library. Are any of [these](http://www.sitepoint.com/9-crazy-jquery-chat-chat-box-plugins/) useful? Or anything else I could follow to make one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the fact that this is *very* easy doable with CSS and that you probably want to style the box anyways, I would not recommend using somthing external here. You just need to set the div which contains to `position: fixed` and then you can control where it appears with `bottom: 0` and `right: 0` to put it in the bottom right corner for example. Then give it a `z-index: 100` for example and you are done with a basic overlay.

Comment: I want some more functionality (like minimizing/maximizing of chatboxes).
Also, I have updated my question.